# Logstash config doesn't parse JSON file and not push data to index - log: {:count=>1,:running_pipelines=>[:main], :non_running_pipelines=>[]}

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-configuration, logstash-file, logstash-filter

I generate a JSON file every 5 mins through a Python code and try to pushing data to Elastic, but the Logstash throw following message and doesn't push any data to Kibana.

My pipeline: File --> Logstash --> Elastic --> Kibana

JSON file output:

```
{
    "platform": "Computer",
    "mode": "Live",
    "users": 899
}
```

Log Message:

```
[INFO ][logstash.agent ] Pipelines running {:count=>1, :running_pipelines=>[:main], :non_running_pipelines=>[]}
```

My Logtash.conf file

```
input {
        file {
                path => "D:/elk/logs_folder/test.json"
                start_position => "beginning"
                sincedb_path => "NUL"
                codec => "json"
        }
}

filter {
  json {
    skip_on_invalid_json => true
    source => "message"
    target => "jsonData"
    add_tag => [ "_message_json_parsed" ]    
  }
}

output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
    index => "in_elk_test"
  }

  stdout{

  }
}
```

I'm getting following error when run Logstash

Log:

```
[INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main] Elasticsearch version determined (8.9.0) {:es_version=>8}
[WARN ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main] Detected a 6.x and above cluster: the `type` event field won't be used to determine the document _type {:es_version=>8}
[INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main] Not eligible for data streams because config contains one or more settings that are not compatible with data streams: {"index"=>"in_elk_test"}
[INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main] Data streams auto configuration (`data_stream => auto` or unset) resolved to `false`
[INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main] Using a default mapping template {:es_version=>8, :ecs_compatibility=>:v8}
[INFO ][logstash.javapipeline    ][main] Starting pipeline {:pipeline_id=>"main", "pipeline.workers"=>16, "pipeline.batch.size"=>125, "pipeline.batch.delay"=>50, "pipeline.max_inflight"=>2000, "pipeline.sources"=>["D:/elk/logstash-8.9.0-windows-x86_64/logstash-8.9.0/logstash-simple.conf"], :thread=>"#<Thread:0x50d159d0@D:/elk/logstash-8.9.0-windows-x86_64/logstash-8.9.0/logstash-core/lib/logstash/java_pipeline.rb:134 run>"}
[INFO ][logstash.javapipeline    ][main] Pipeline Java execution initialization time {"seconds"=>1.05}
[INFO ][logstash.inputs.file     ][main] No sincedb_path set, generating one based on the "path" setting {:sincedb_path=>"D:/elk/logstash-8.9.0-windows-x86_64/logstash-8.9.0/data/plugins/inputs/file/.sincedb_f2779ebeeb58467d208ce626cfa73491", :path=>["D:/elk/logs_folder/logs1.json"]}
[INFO ][logstash.javapipeline    ][main] Pipeline started {"pipeline.id"=>"main"}
[INFO ][filewatch.observingtail  ][main][223ec84e00c300043960ade7a8b1b9aa2a896b167223b1bf197e641e0ac119cd] START, creating Discoverer, Watch with file and sincedb collections
[INFO ][logstash.agent           ] Pipelines running {:count=>1, :running_pipelines=>[:main], :non_running_pipelines=>[]}
```

After the statement, Logstash doesn't parse my JSON file and not pushing data to index.

[image]

Please help me on figuring out the issue and address it, Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

> [INFO ][logstash.inputs.file     ][main] No sincedb_path set, generating one based on the "path" setting {:sincedb_path=>"D:/elk/logstash-8.9.0-windows-x86_64/logstash-8.9.0/data/plugins/inputs/file/.sincedb_f2779ebeeb58467d208ce626cfa73491", :path=>["D:/elk/logs_folder/logs1.json"]}

In your file input you also need to set a `sincedb_path` to make sure that you read your file from the beginning, otherwise if you've started Logstash a few times, it will read from the end of the file

```
    file {
            path => "D:/elk/logs_folder/test.json"
            start_position => "beginning"
            sincedb_path => "NUL"
            codec => "json"
    }
```

Comment: I have added sincedb_path => "NUL", but still facing same issue and stuck at the same place  Pipelines running {:count=>1, :running_pipelines=>[:main], :non_running_pipelines=>[]}, Could you check?

Comment: Since you have `skip_on_invalid_json => true` are you certain that your file contains valid JSON data, one record per line?

Comment: My JSON file isn't in single line, its in 3 lines as shown in the question

Comment: Oh, my bad, I overlooked it, that's why it doesn't work then, JSON logs need to be on a single line

Comment: I have changed the JSON file as single line {"platform": "Computer", "mode": "Live", "users": 226} -- still same issue and I have tried again without filter plugin, still no luck, getting same line, no parse after that

Comment: Is there a newline after each line? i.e. each JSON MUST be one its own line

Comment: No newline in the JSON file.

Comment: Then add some and it will work